# Map object to entity of this object from another module

Tags: java, object

Let's say I have got `User` object with 2 `properties`: `id`, `name`.
This object is placed in `domain` module and the full hierarchy of modules looks like that:
`domain` -> `service` -> `web`.
In my `web` module I also have `UserEntity`.
I need to map my object from `User` to `UserEntity` in `RepositoryImplementation` class which is placed in `web` module.
So I tried to make method in my `User` class from `domain` module

```
public UserEntity toUserEntity() {
    return UserEntity
               .builder().id(id).name(name).build();
}
```

but I realised that I just do not have access to `classes` from `web` module because the `web` module "inherits" from `domain`, not in reverse.

I do not use `getters` and `setters` in my `User` class because of `TDA` convention so I do not have direct access to properties of this object

Is there any idea how can I do this mapping method?

Comment: Well ... turn it around. Have a method `UserEntity fromUser(User user)` in your class `UserEntity`.

Comment: Yep, I tried do this even before but I do not use `getters` and `setters` in my `User` class because of `TDA` convention so I do not have direct access to properties of this `object`

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it and even some libraries to help you. But on all of those solutions, the main point is that converter should be in the module which has access to both covertable class and the class to be converted to.

Or in other words. Converter does not have to be in the `User` class. It may be a different class (e.g `UserConverter`) which should be in a module which sees both `User` and `UserEntity`.